# When is the CD environment variable updated?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The tipp to use the `CD` environment variable from batch scripts to get the current working directory is commonly posted.  But `CD` won't get updated when `call`ing another batch file.  Then the `cd` command echoes the new path of the other batch file, but `%CD%` (or `!CD!`) is not updated. Example:

```
@echo off
 cd %~dp0
 echo in %0: CD=%CD%
 pause
 call X:\testcall.cmd
```

Save this as `C:\testcall.cmd` and `X:\testcall.cmd`, then run `C:\testcall.cmd`. You should see that the value of `CD` has not changed. This seems not to dependend on `call`; none of the following works:

```
start /D <NEW_DIR> <OTHER_CMD_FILE>
start cmd /c <NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
cmd /c <NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
<NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
cd %~dp0
pushd %~dp0
```

`CD` will keep it's old value, while `cd` (the command) shows the correct directory. Therefore I set `CD` at the begin of a script:

```
set CD=%~dp0
```

...while assuming *cmd.exe* sets `CD` only if this variable is yet unset. True?

Comment: Where do you echo the `%CD%` in the caller batch or in the called batch?

Comment: If you explicitly set `CD` with `set CD=...` you can't access the pseudo variable `CD` anymore

Comment: You shouldn't save your example as _c:\testcall.cmd_ AND _X:\testcall.cmd_, as _X:\testcall.cmd_ will end up in an endless loop

Comment: Your expection of the result is wrong, the result itself is quite correct

Comment: The endless loop is prevented by `pause`. This is just minimal test script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build two batch files from your comment

**test1.bat** - located in **C:\temp**

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
echo File %~f CD=%CD%
call X:\test2.bat
```

**test2.bat** - located in **X:**

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
echo File %~f CD=%CD%
```

Starting **test1** it from **C:\temp**, the output is

```
File C:\temp\test1.bat CD=C:\temp 
File X:\test2.bat CD=C:\temp
```

**The result is absolutly correct!**

Starting a batch file (or any other program) with an absolute or relative path doesn't change the current directory.

The *CD* seems to fail, as *CD* can't change the drive the way you used it.

You need to **add a switch** `CD /d %~dp0`

Comment: Not mixing... maybe my short example was incomplete. As I wrote in the initial question a `cd %~dp0`, `pushd` or `start /D` does not update `CD` either. You can test this by putting a `cd %~dp0` on top of the test script. The only way to get the true working directory seems to be calling `cd` on top of the script, and set `CD` explicitly. But this looks like a hack - therefore this thread.

Comment: Ok, but now it becomes clear. `CD` will not change your directory without `/D` switch

Comment: Interesting... only `cd /D` really updates `CD`. I tested it by calling a script on different drives, and another directory on the same drive. Only `cd /D` updates `CD` in both cases. Obviously this was intended by Microsoft: by adding `/D` they did not want to break the existing behavior of setting `CD` only if yet unset. **So this is the solution.**

Answer (score 7):

`%CD%` is the *current directory*, while `%~dp0` is the directory of the currently-running script (with trailing '\').

Also, don't set an env. var called `CD`, since it will override the default %CD% pseudo-var, and will be incredibly confusing - see [OldNewThing - ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx).

For example, when running c:\temp\a.cmd, which is:

```
@echo off
echo Currently running script: %~dpnx0
cd %~dp0
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%
cd %~dp0a
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%
set CD=bogus value
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%
```

output:

```
Currently running script: c:\temp\a.cmd
scriptDir=c:\temp\, CD=c:\temp
scriptDir=c:\temp\, CD=c:\temp\a
scriptDir=c:\temp\, CD=bogus value
```

Answer (score 4):

**Diagnosis**

You have at some point set the `CD` variable explicitly. If you do this it will no longer automatically reflect the current working directory. To undo this, set it to empty:

```
set CD=
```

It will then begin working again.

Why is this? Well, the automatic CD variable was introduced as a feature. I assume they just didn't want to break pre-existing scripts which already used that varible name. So if you set it explicitly, CMD will assume you are doing so on purpose.

**Discussion**

Firstly,  if the parent process has an explicitly set `CD` variable, it will be inherited by the child processes.

On the other hand, you shouldn't expect any of these to update the value of `%CD%` for the parent process:

```
start /D <NEW_DIR> <OTHER_CMD_FILE>
start cmd /c <NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
cmd /c <NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
```

These all create new processes, the new process then changes its own working directory. You should  not expect this to affect the parent process.

The final one, does not update the working directory at all, unless OTHER_CMD_FILE executes a CD command:

```
<NEW_DIR>\<OTHER_CMD_FILE>
```

Just because you executed a script in a different directory does not mean that the script's working directory will change. **The script working directory does not have to be set to the location of the script.**

**Advice**

Relying on the working directory being set to anything in particular is generally a bad idea.

You probably want something like this:

```
SET SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
```

Then use (for example) `"%SCRIPT_DIR%\config.txt"` to refer to a file in that directory.

Alternatively if you wish to rely on the current directory, use `cd /d %~dp0`

Comment: `CD` was not set explicitly. When set by _cmd_ initially it will also stick at its value. The key probably is what you said: `CD` was never truely implemented by M$. Therefore `set CD=%~dp0` seems to be the solution, as `CD` is a standard variable, and I find it to complicate, generally, to introduce another variable for the same thing. When you see variables like `SCRIPT_DIR` in a (bigger) script you always wonder how and where it is set; for `CD` the meaning is inherent.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler, You seem to think that the WORKING directory and the SCRIPT directory are the same thing - they are not the same thing at all. If %CD% doesn't reflect the current WORKING directory, it means that it has been set explicitly, either by the current script, or by another script which has run previously, or by the calling process. Also, CD and SCRIPT_DIR (or %~dp0) do not mean the same thing. SCRIPT_DIR or %~dp0 would be the location of the script file. CD is the current working directory, which may not be the same.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler: Setting the value of CD variable is a very bad idea. Think for a moment what would happen if someone tries to set the value of DATE or TIME variables. And the answer to your thought is: YES, all these variables are of the same type!

Comment: +1, good advice.  But be aware if you run a batch file from a UNC path name (\\myserver\myshare\myfile.bat), then cd /d %~dp0 won't work. Instead use pushd which will create a temporary drive letter for UNC paths.

Comment: @Aacine: Setting `DATE` would be bad; but isn't it actually a bug NOT to update `CD`? If you see the use of `CD` in the code, wouldn't you expect it to return the current working directory? At least the out-of-the-box-behavior is not comprehensible; it can be dangerous to rely on `CD` when branching back and forth between batch files.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler, `SET CD=` is your answer. If you do that it will again reflect the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `%cd%` variable to whatever you want, the **real current** directory for the `C:` drive is stored in the `%=c:%` variable, and you can't change this with the `set` command:

```
@echo off
echo Currently running script: %~dpnx0
cd %~dp0
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%
set CD=bogus value
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%, =c:=%=c:%
set =c:=bogus value
echo scriptDir=%~dp0, CD=%CD%, =c:=%=c:%
```

Output is:

```
Currently running script: C:\OldDir\a.bat
scriptDir=C:\OldDir\, CD=bogus value
scriptDir=C:\OldDir\, CD=bogus value, =c:=C:\OldDir
syntax error.
scriptDir=C:\OldDir\, CD=bogus value, =c:=C:\OldDir
```

The `=C:` variable for a child process is always set from the parent process. If you avoid the `setlocal` command in your script OR choose `endlocal`, you can change persistend the current directory for the current cmd session:

```
C:\OldDir>type script.bat
cd c:\newdir

C:\OldDir>script

C:\OldDir>cd c:\newdir

C:\NewDir>
```

.

```
C:\OldDir>type script.bat
setlocal
cd c:\newdir

C:\OldDir>script

C:\OldDir>setlocal

C:\OldDir>cd c:\newdir

C:\OldDir>
```

Comment: `%=c:` doesn't contain the *real current directory*, it contains only the current directory for drive C: and `%=d:%` contains the current dir of drive D:. So you don't know which is the *real* current drive

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Edited my answer. Every volume has it's own "current directory". Its impossible to rename the `%=X:` directory, if it is set. It is set on the first access of a volume.

Answer (score 0):

Using the script-directory `%~dp0` can be a solution, but usually isn't. This works better:

```
cd >tmpfile
set /P CD= <tmpfile
del tmpfile
```

This solution is consistent with the `CD` variable. `CD` [contains the current directory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting), not ending in a slash character if it is not in the root directory of the current drive. The path printed by `cd` behaves exactly so.

I'm using this for years and had no problems setting `CD` explicitly. Later I began using `PWD` (as in Bash).  This variable is not reserved in MSDOS.  So my question here was actually: "Can we get rid of these lines, or is this some MSDOS idiom?"

Some have written that setting `CD` explicitly is bad. Why? MSODS was never properly designed, and is not further developed. Anything you can do with it is legal. There is no bad MSDOS programming - just good and bad hacks. I know no other language where this perspective is legal to such an extent.

Comment: This isn't necessary, the `CD` variable contains always the correct directory. Sometimes you can't access it via `%CD%` in blocks, but that's not a problem of `CD` itself.

Comment: Have you really read this thread? It is not updated properly if you `call` batch scripts back and forth.

Comment: Please show an example with one or two batch files where it fails. I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: Thanks for asking for some concrete code; you're right (+1). Simple `call` a batch file on another drive, like `@echo off & echo in %0: CD=%CD% & pause & call X:\testcall.cmd`.  Save this code as _C:\testcall.cmd_ and _X:\testcall.cmd_ (but these are just two arbitary drives). When running _C:\testcall.cmd_ you should see that the value of `CD` remains the same. Tested on Windows 7, Version 6.1.7601.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler, tested on Window 7, Version 6.1 build 7601. Value of `%CD%` remained the same, i.e. `in c:\testcall.cmd: CD=C:\` and `in Z:\testcall.cmd: CD=C:\`. I believe you have at some point set it explicitly, causing it to no longer reflect the current working directory.